# How to redirect view in separate target window

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using visual studio 2012 and mvc4.

I want to open **CertDet** view in **separate window**

In index view I have used submit with post method.

My Controller -

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(ModelCertificate cert)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            dbRTCEntities objCon = new dbRTCEntities();
            Mst_Catref data = objCon.Mst_Catref.Where(x => x.Catref == cert.Catref).FirstOrDefault();

            if (data != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("CertDet", new { catref = data.Catref, Excise = cert.ExciseNumber, customerNm = cert.CustomerName });                    
            }
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Catref not found");
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult CertDet(string catref, string Excise, string customerNm)
    {
        dbRTCEntities objCon = new dbRTCEntities();
        Mst_Catref data = objCon.Mst_Catref.Where(x => x.Catref == catref).FirstOrDefault();
        ModelCertificate cert = new ModelCertificate();

        return View(cert);
    }
```

Comment: You could show your view as well..

Answer (score 0):

You should need something like this on your View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("CertDet", "CertDet", new { catref = data.Catref, Excise = cert.ExciseNumber, customerNm = cert.CustomerName }, new {target = "_blank"})
```

This will render something like this in a new window;

```
<a href="/CertDet/?certref=xyz&Excise=abc&customerNm=123" target="_blank">CertDet</a>
```